# onCreateContextMenu- NPE

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, contextmenu

I am developing a code in which, a context menu should pop up on long-clicking a list-view item.This worked previously but don't know why it is a NPE now. Please see my code below and suggest.

```
public void displayImages(){
//some other functionality
 imageAdapter = new GoodAdapter(this, imageBeanArray);
    list.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    registerForContextMenu(list);
}

 @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Rename");
    menu.add(0,v.getId(),0,"Delete");
}

 @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    final ImageBean imageBean = imageBeanArray.get(info.position);
    final int selectedImageId= imageBean.getId();

   if(item.getTitle()=="Rename") {//Do some thing}
   else if (item.getTitle()=="Rename") {//Do some thing else}
 }
```

Layout Declaration of List view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/menu"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Logcat says:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kittu.ClientLync, PID: 30281
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2694)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
            at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:4752)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:3538)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:3494)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you provide the layout declaration of your ListView?

Comment: @PaulLammertsma: Please find the layout XML code. Sorry, I wasnt able to add it as a XML code. Dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you cannot use `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL)` in conjunction with a context menu. As your layout XML already (correctly) provides `android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"`, you may safely remove the code override to `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`.

Comment: Seems like you are true.The code is working fine now after removing the override. Thanks bud. But, is there any logic behind this? Just wondering, can't there be a case in which user can select multiple items (checkbox) and the same list can have contextmenu on top of each list item? any thoughts on this...